# How to copy a value from an input box into the inside of a Jquery Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set a dynamic value to a Jquery Script.

**GOAL:**
Copy value from `amounter` to  `"amount": "HERE",` inside the script.

**Here is my code:**

```
<button id="rzp-button6">Pay with Razorpay</button>

<form name='razorpayform'>
    <input type="text" name="amounter" id="amounter" value="">

</form>


<script>

var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_s7jZhwh0czdxMH",
    "name": "Arijit Aich",
    "amount": "1200",
    "description": "Testing Payment",
    "image": "http://www.google.com/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png",
    "handler": function (response){

       $("#razorpayform").html(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    var rpid = response.razorpay_payment_id;
    window.location = '/invoice.php?billno=' + rpid;

    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Arijit Aich",
        "email": "XXXXX@gmail.com",
        "contact": "7121212120"
    },
    "notes": {
        "shopping_id": "q3123kjanjk"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
}


var rzp6 = new Razorpay(options);

document.getElementById('rzp-button6').onclick = function(e){
    rzp6.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}

</script>
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/00fnopqj/1/

Comment: options.amount = $('#amounter').val() to grab input value

Answer (score 2):

Create the `new Razorpay` inside the click event handler so you can set the amount property first

```
$('#rzp-button6').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   options.amount = $('#amounter').val();
   var rzp6 = new Razorpay(options);   
   rzp6.open()
});
// or do similar in your `onclick`
```

Comment: Tried with the above mentioned code. Kept the "amount": "1200", part intact in the jquery code. Didn't work.

Comment: *"Didn't work"* isn't a real problem statement...what happened? What errors were thrown ... etc?

Comment: I placed this code above the button tag inside <script></script>. Removed the  "amount": "1200", part inside the payment jquery. Ran the code. The gateway is responding but without the amount value.

Comment: move it below the button tag or wrap it in a load event handler. Also may need to convert string to number...not sure what the api expects. Note that my jQuery `click()` approach is a replacement for your `onclick` also

Comment: All the edits are redirecting to 0 value. I have updated my answer with a testing KEY so that even you guys can try it out yourself. The key would expire within 24 hours though.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle or other sand box

Comment: Done. Updated my answer with a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from the input

```
var value = document.getElementById("amounter").value;
```

To set the value in the object

```
options.amount = value;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the entire code and provide the changes inside that? I am really getting confused on where to put them and how.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the input

```
amount: $('#amounter').val()
```

or with dot notation

```
document.getElementById('rzp-button6').onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    options.amount = $('#amounter').val();
    var rzp6 = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp6.open();
}
```

Comment: @ArijitAich inside the button onclick.

Comment: Should i remove the "amount": "1200", part in the payment jqeury code?

Comment: You don't have to, the value is going to change to the value inside the input.

Comment: Well then it didn't. Will it be possible to copy my whole code and make the necessary changes and then update your answer? I am really not a Jquery guy.

Comment: your edit should still call new RazorPay inside onclick ... the original amount would already have been passed into it if you don't

Comment: @ArijitAich i have updated my answer, this will work for you.

Comment: All the edits are redirecting to 0 value. I have updated my answer with a testing KEY so that even you guys can try it out yourself. The key would expire within 24 hours though.